# Returning Data without Accesing a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

The Situation (Ignore this it is boring):
I have reports that I created using reporting services. Some of these reports take the parameter, "Month". They enter in an integer for the month they want. Example: December = 12.
In order to view the report, I am simply using the Report Viewer in visual studio. I need the month field to be a drop down box in order to select the month by name. There is a feature in in reporting services that allows you to bind the field to a stored procedure in order to create value/text pairs for the drop down list.

The Problem:
I don't want to create a "months" table in my database but I need to have a stored procedure that can return all the month/int pairs. I'm sure there is a very easy solution to this but I'm not sure what it is!  My first thought was creating a temp table, but I am not sure how to add manually add each month/int pair to the table... All your suggestions are appreciated!

What I want is the following statement, except without the use of the Months Table:

```
SELECT MonthID, MonthName
FROM Months
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ListMonths
AS

    SELECT 1 AS MonthId, 'January' AS MonthName
     union all select 2, 'February'
     union all select 3, 'March'
     union all select 4, 'April'
     union all select 5, 'May'
     union all select 6, 'June'
     union all select 7, 'July'
     union all select 8, 'August'
     union all select 9, 'September'
     union all select 10, 'October'
     union all select 11, 'November'
     union all select 12, 'December'

GO
```

Call this and I believe it returns what you want.

Comment: Much better than creating a table. Perfect Solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need to create a table for this? You could just do the selects manually:

```
SELECT 1, 'January' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'February' UNION ALL
...
SELECT 12, 'December'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you need is a view, basically you write a custom query and it returns it as a table.

Also, a SP can just contain a Query and it will return a table, just create it as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[mytable] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @inputarg1 = 0
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT  
        .....
    FROM
        .....
    WHERE
        .....
END
```

Answer (score 1):

in the stored proc, do the following

```
Declare @Months Table 
   (monthNo TinyInt Primary Key Not Null,
    name varChar(10) Not Null,
    Abbrev char(3) = Substring(name,1,3))
Insert @Months ( monthNo, name) Values (1, 'January')
Insert @Months ( monthNo, name) Values (2, 'February')
...
Insert @Months ( monthNo, name) Values (12, 'December')
```

or, if you need this table in more than one stored proc, write a UDF that dies the same thing and returns this table to the calling proc...

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!
BTW, you have the Abbreviation field, but you are not adding the abbreviation to the inserts. Thanks!

Comment: The abbreviation field is a calculated column, based on the first three characters of the name field... (thought I'd add that twist as a bonus!)

Comment: Ahh. Sorry I unchecked this, but I think I'm better off without creating the table. Thanks!

Comment: hey, that's fine, no problem, but so you realize, this table is an in memory table only that only exists as long as the stotred proc is running... and then it dissappears

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH    months AS
        (
        SELECT  CAST('2009.01.01' AS DATETIME) AS m, 1 AS num
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  DATEADD(month, 1, m), num + 1
        FROM    months
        WHERE   num < 12
        )
SELECT  num, DATENAME(month, m)
FROM    months
```